# Getting subclass

Tags: java, oop, casting, subclass, superclass

That's my short Example. SuperClass:

```
public abstract class SuperClass
{
    public SubClass getSubClass()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

SubClass extending SuperClass:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    public SubClass getSubClass()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public static void doSomething(SuperClass instance)
    {
        if(instance instanceof SubClass)
        {
            //Option 1:
            SubClass example1 = instance.getSubClass();
            //Option 2:
            SubClass example2 = (SubClass)instance;
        }
    }
}
```

My Question is, what's the best(and without any warnings) way to get SubClass?

In option 1, i will get 2 warnings(1. in SuperClass#getSubClass that Class references Subclass, 2. in SubClass#getSubClass that it ignores method in SuperClass).

In option 2, i will get 1 warning(Casting to concrete Class) and i believe that option is slower too.

Is there any other way to achieve what i want? Which option is the best?

Comment: I don't what you are trying to achieve. Method chaining but with a method in parent class?

Comment: Just do `public SuperClass getSubClass() { return this; }` in super class.

Comment: yo are messing everything up. The father shouldn't know about the child. And the ´instance of´ make no sense at all because you already know it

Comment: You should not have `SuperClass` depend on `SubClass` in any way, so both ways are bad practice.

Comment: @iberbeu And that's why we have the Maury Povitch show.

Comment: @user3009344 Answer this question for all of us. Which of the following is more true? 
`A SubClass IS A SuperClass` or
`A SuperClass HAS A SubClass`

Comment: A SubClass IS A SuperClass. So i should avoid both examples right?

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this is through the `instanceof` operator, but the way you are using it currently it doesn't add anything (`instance` must be an `instanceof` `SuperClass`, since that is it's type when it's declared.

```
public void doSomething(final SuperClass superClass) {
    if (superClass instanceof SubClass) {
        final SubClass subClass = (SubClass) superClass;
    } else if (superClass instanceof AnotherSubClass) {
        final AnotherSubClass anotherSubClass = (AnotherSubClass) superClass;
    }
}
```

This should not give you any compiler warnings.

Comment: Sorry, i changed that line to (instance instanceof SubClass), it was made by mistake previously